mapStruct isn't reusing already defined mappers
I have the following mappers:
@Mapper(uses = { IItemMapper.class, IChainMapper.class, ICountryMapper.class, IForecastFeatureMapper.class })
public interface IForecastMapper {

    ForecastModel fromForecastDTOToForecastModel(ForecastDTO dto);
}

@Mapper
public interface ICountryMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "name", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "acronym", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "status", ignore = true)
    CountryModel fromForecastDTOToCountryModel(ForecastDTO forecastDTO);
}

Given that the object ForecastModel is built like below:
@Entity
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "forecast")
public class ForecastModel implements Serializable {

    @Serial private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @UuidGenerator
    @com.enterprise.b2b.api.service.common.hibernate.constraint.UUID
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private CountryModel countryId;
}

Isn't mapStruct supposed to use the fromForecastDTOToCountryModel method from ICountryMapper inside fromForecastDTOToForecastModel method from IForecastMapper?
Instead of it mapStruct is generating a protected method inside the implementation like this:
protected CountryModel forecastDTOToCountryModel(ForecastDTO forecastDTO) {
    if ( forecastDTO == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    CountryModel.CountryModelBuilder countryModel = CountryModel.builder();

    if ( forecastDTO.getCountryId() != null ) {
        countryModel.id( UUID.fromString( forecastDTO.getCountryId() ) );
    }

    return countryModel.build();
}

Even when I try to force using @Mapping annotation, mapStruct is still generating the method, for example:
@Mapper(uses = { IItemMapper.class, IChainMapper.class, ICountryMapper.class, IForecastFeatureMapper.class }, imports = Mappers.class)
public interface IForecastMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "countryId", expression = "java(Mappers.getMapper(ICountryMapper.class).fromForecastDTOToCountryModel(dto))")
    ForecastModel fromForecastDTOToForecastModel(ForecastDTO dto);
}

mapStruct simply ignores the expression and generates the method. I am using mapStruct 1.6.2.
Any thoughts?

pls, provide ForecastDTO also
